# Computed property is not triggering v-if block

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and I get lost with the watch/computed properties. I've already checked other answers on SO but none seem to be helpful.

I'm building an extremely basic auth check mechanism, where I store a value in localStorage and check it to see if I can show a component or not.

My v-if block if not behaving as expected, it triggers after a reload, instead of triggering pre-render. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav id="navigation" v-if="isAuthenticated">
                <div class="navigation-header">
                    <h3>Some content</h3>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div id="content">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light inset-shadow" v-if="isAuthenticated">
                    <p>some content</p>
                </nav>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        computed: {
            isAuthenticated: function() {
                if (localStorage.getItem('authenticated') === 'true') {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `localStorage` is not reactive so the value of the computed property will never change from its initial value.

Comment: Then using a method andd running it pre-render (created() for example) should work, but it doesn't, it still requires a page refresh

Comment: Are you sure isAuthenticated() is actually returning true? Seems to work fine when it does: https://codeply.com/p/KCoVwYRdE2

Comment: @OscarCarballal Using a method will avoid the caching problem but it still won't cause the component to re-render when the contents of `localStorage` changes. Only changing reactive data will do that. You'll need to ensure that when you change the contents of `localStorage` it also updates something reactive and then have your template use that instead of trying to use `localStorage` directly.

Comment: @Zim yes, it's returning the expected value at the right time

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method instead to check the authenticated user and ran the method in the created() or mounted() block. Or you can use vuex which is a much better option

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The if block doesn't reevaluate until I reload. created() is supposed to run before rendering, but for some reason the if blocl doesn't react.